# Prove that $\sum\limits _{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}\cos\left(2\pi nt\right)=\sum\limits _{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}\delta\left(t-n\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I've tried using Fourier transforms on both but didn't quite get anything useful.
I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: In a math forum (as opposed to a physics forum) you need to say what sort of objects these are and what sort of convergence you want.  Clearly this is not a pointwise equation of functions of $t$.

Comment: @GEdgar It doesn't quite specify this information but this was in the context of Fourier transforms and applied math.

Comment: I think your equality does not hold. Each side is the Fourier transform of the other, it looks, when regarded as tempered distributions.

Comment: @DanielFischer could you provide some further explanation?

Comment: Hmm, it looks as though by the Poisson sum formula, the two are indeed the same, the one is the Fourier series of the other too.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, but I'm not really familiar with it, could you maybe elaborate and post it as an answer? (plus, this will make it easier to discuss it :) )

Comment: Guess at the meaning.  If $\phi$ is a continuous function with compact support, then $\sum\limits _{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\cos\left(2\pi nt\right)\phi(t)dt=\sum\limits _{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}\phi(n)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing on the right is a periodic  distribution with period $1$. So we can expand it into a Fourier series in terms of $\cos 2\pi n t$ and $\sin 2\pi n t$. The coefficients of sines are all $0$, because 
$$b_n=2\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \delta(t)\sin 2\pi n t\,dt = 2\sin (2\pi n \cdot 0) =0$$
The cosine coefficients are 
$$a_n=2\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \delta(t)\cos 2\pi n t\,dt = 2\cos (2\pi n \cdot 0) =2$$
Hence, the expansion is 
$$1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos 2\pi n t \tag{1}$$
which is the same as $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \cos 2\pi n t$ because cosines are even. The series (1) converges, in the sense of distributions, to the distribution $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\delta(t-n)$.